# changing mysql configuration . Getting errors like Table is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, configuration

On Our server I have done following configuration for Database: [server has 2 core, 2 GB ram and windows 2008 operating system]

> query_cache_size=         32M
>   [Old] query_cache_size=         50M
>   [New]
>
> thread_cache_size=        8
>   [Old] thread_cache_size=        100
>   [New]
>
> key_buffer_size=             384M
>   [Old] key_buffer_size=             600M
>   [New]
>
> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
>   [Old] innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
>   [New]
>
> innodb_buffer_pool_size=16M
>   [Old] innodb_buffer_pool_size=250M
>   [New]
>
> innodb_thread_concurrency= 0
>   [New] innodb_read_io_threads=       64
>   [New] innodb_write_io_threads=     64
>   [New]

though application was working fine but now i am having a problem regarding mysql table getting crashed.

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1194 Table 'mytable' is marked as crashed and should be repaired. The SQL statement executed wa....

My sql version is 5.5.17

Comment: Has something changed recently? There are already [questions which covers the scenario and solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915604/mysql-said-1194-table-tablename-is-marked-as-crashed-and-should-be-repaire)... (go through it and other similar questions) BTW, default storage engine in 5.5 is Innodb, do you still have MyISAM tables? Do you consider moving to InnoDB?

Comment: is the engine MyISAM? how often does it crash?

Comment: Those tables crashed are all MyIsam

Comment: I hope you are not actually putting "[New]" in the config file -- that would confuse mysql.

Comment: After a power failure, some MyISAM tables need to be `CHECKed` and possibly `REPAIRed`.  This has nothing to do with the config changes.